# IIS: Cannot access a https web-service from remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, iis

Update: It works from test console up. It does not work from Windows Store Metro app. I do believe problem is with WCF compatibility with Windows Store apps.

I'm hosting a WCF web-service over https in my local IIS instance. When testing service reference in the client for it on local machine everything works just fine. When running the client from the other machine on local network following exception is received:

System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 10.10.4.60:443

The service is implemented like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232.aspx).

Remote machine can browse service.svc?wsdl but it cannot open service.svc in browser - it pops up 403 forbidden exception. Is there a problem with website permissions in IIS?

Also I get SSL errors while trying to browse just directory of svc file in browser from remote machine.

Comment: Did you check if the firewall blocks the 443 port ?

Comment: Yes, we've tested it with firewall and anti-virus disabled, still it does not work.

Comment: Can you telnet to port 443 ?

Comment: It works from test console client app. It does not work from Windows Store Metro app. Maybe some WCF features like transport security not supported on Metro?

Comment: What does failed request tracing (IIS) write?

Comment: Before moving on, first read IIS log files to see which sub status of 403 you hit, https://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891

Comment: I do not see anything about this request in IIS logs or failed request tracing. It fails at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream with "Unable to connect to the remote server" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a network error - request was not even registering in IIS logs.